# Return 2 digit computation even if result is 1 digit MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make the results of CONCAT(ROUND(oi.OutboundUnits/oi.OutboundCalls *100),'%') AS OutboundConv return in a 2 digit format even if the result is 9 or below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LPAD function, with a different condition for 100% using the CASE statement, as below:

```
CASE
    WHEN ROUND(oi.OutboundUnits/oi.OutboundCalls *100) = 100 THEN '100%'
    ELSE LPAD(CONCAT(ROUND(oi.OutboundUnits/oi.OutboundCalls *100),'%'), 3, '0')
END
```

**Reference**:

[LPAD on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Comment: Are you able to explain the need for the WHEN ROUND(oi.OutboundUnits/oi.OutboundCalls *100) = 100 THEN '100%'? While the procedure gives me what I want, it now makes those converting at 100% sort improperly compared to the values that have had CONCAT applied. Any suggestions?

Comment: LPAD makes the string to be 3 characters long padding with zeros for shorter values. So, 4% would be 04%, 34% would be 34%. However 100% would become 100, leaving the % out. So, 100% needs to be handled differently, and therefore the CASE statement is used.

Comment: If the sorting is not done properly, I would recommend sorting based on the numeric values, as `ORDER BY ROUND(oi.OutboundUnits/oi.OutboundCalls *100)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat and right function.

```
right(concat('0', OutboundConv), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or there's the [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function:

`format(oi.OutboundUnits/oi.OutboundCalls,2)`

So, as a simple example:
`format (5/2, 2)` will return `2.50`